# How to convert a line of alphanumeric strings into 3 different parts

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Assume I get the following input from a scanner : `"5B1 2B2 9B3 1R4 3R5 8R6 10R7"`

I would like to have the data saved in something similar to this:

```
array[0]  = {5,B,1}
array[1]  = {2,B,2}
```

**NOTE:** I need the number on the left side of the character saved a WHOLE.
**Example:** I need `10R7` to be saved as `{10,R,7}` and not `{1,0,R,7}`

Using this:

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String[] nodes = input.split(" ");
```

I was able to achieve the array containing {5B1,3B2} etc..

**EDIT:**

I tried this approach(WORKS) :

```
String[][] aa = new String[nodes.length][];
for(int i =0; i<nodes.length; i++ ){
   aa[i] = nodes[i].split("((?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z]))");
}
```

This occurs if you print straight away:

```
   [Ljava.lang.String;@55f96302
   [Ljava.lang.String;@3d4eac69
   [Ljava.lang.String;@42a57993
   [Ljava.lang.String;@75b84c92
   [Ljava.lang.String;@6bc7c054
   [Ljava.lang.String;@232204a1
   [Ljava.lang.String;@4aa298b7
```

The above issue only occurs if I try to print it using:

```
System.out.println(aa[i]);
```

There is another way of printing it but I don't need to print it.

Comment: char only takes one character at a time.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: use `split(" ")` with space then use `split("")` without space you will get your char array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split `\\s` to get your words, then you can use `s.toCharArray()` to array of char:

```
String str = "5B1 2B2 9B3 1R4 3R5 8R6 10R7";
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
String spl[] = str.split("\\s+");

for (String s : spl) {
   String sp[] = s.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1-").replaceAll("([0-9]+)", "$1-").split("-");
   list.add(sp);
}
```

Print your array :

```
list.forEach((rs) -> {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rs));
});
```

This can gives you :

```
[5, B, 1]
[2, B, 2]
[9, B, 3]
[1, R, 4]
[3, R, 5]
[8, R, 6]
[10, R, 7]
```

Comment: what about \\s+ ?

Comment: how can I get [10,R,7] for the last one instead of [1,0,R,7]?

Comment: in this case you have to use another way, you have to use String instead and not char @MostafaOsama if you want this case, i will do another way

Comment: Yes my bad, I will use String indeed. Can you please show me how?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = in.nextLine(); // Read 5B1 2B2 9B3 1R4 3R5 8R6 10R7 from user

    String[] sArr = str.split(" "); // break into array of string ["5B1", "2B2", .... "10R7"]

    char[][] cArr = new char[sArr.length][]; // create a 2D char array to save the string array
    int idx = 0;

    for(String s : sArr){
        cArr[idx++] = s.toCharArray(); // [['5','B','1'], ['2','B','2'], ...]
    }

    //Print the array
    for(char[] c1 : cArr){
        for(char c2: c1){
            System.out.print(c2 + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alright so after some playing around I found a fix:

For anyone who might have something similar here it is:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String[] nodes = input.split(" ");

String[][] aa = new String[nodes.length][];

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    aa[i] = nodes[i].split("((?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z]))");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "5B1 2B2 9B3 1R4 3R5 8R6 10R7";

    // split input string by spaces first
    // convert every chunk into char array
    List<char[]> result =
            Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).stream().map(String::toCharArray).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (char[] r : result) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
    }
}
```

output:

```
[5, B, 1]
[2, B, 2]
[9, B, 3]
[1, R, 4]
[3, R, 5]
[8, R, 6]
[1, 0, R, 7]
```

Comment: can I have it in such a way that the output is {10,R,7}?

Comment: @Lashane How can I achieve that?

Comment: @MostafaOsama print `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end

Comment: @Lashane I am afraid I don't get your explanation

Comment: @MostafaOsama do you know how to print one symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string

```
String str = "5B1 2B2 9B3 1R4 3R5 8R6 10R7"
String[] parts = str.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(parts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Questions is related to char[] not String[].